# how to configure Telephony.Sms.Conversations and set the result to a listview adapter

Tags: android, messaging

i want to get all conversations in list view, i didn't find any example of Telephony.Sms.Conversations
I have used content://sms/inbox but this shows all the inbox messaged, instead i want to get conversation. but i did't find any example content://sms/conversations

Answer (score 0):

i have done, code is bellow

```
public static void getAllMessagesInList(Context context) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
    String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "recipient_ids", "message_count", "snippet", "date", "read" };
    Cursor cursor = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, reqCols, null, null, "date DESC");

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            MessageBoxObject messageBoxObject = new MessageBoxObject();

            messageBoxObject.setThreadId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[0])));
            messageBoxObject.setRecipient_ids(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[1])));
            messageBoxObject.setMessage_count(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[2])));
            messageBoxObject.setSnippet(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[3])));
            messageBoxObject.setDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[4])));
            messageBoxObject.setRead(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[5])));

            if (messageBoxObject.getMessage_count() > 0) {
                ConstantsValues.messageBoxObjects.add(messageBoxObject);
            }

        }
    }
    cursor.close();

}
```

then in adapter

get the values by getters